# Query of crystal reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have to calculate Hours as well as days (calculating Perfectly). 
my problem is i have no idea of query of crystal report but i have search the method of calculate hours after the days (like 5 days and 6 hours) on my hospital project bill..

the method i have searced is this 
Sql Query..... Tell me how to deploy this to my crystal report query

```
declare @firstdate int = (select DATEDIFF (hh,AdmitPatientBed.StartDate , AdmitPatientBed.EndDate) from AdmitPatientBed where APBId = 4)

declare @seconddate int = (select DATEDIFF (Day, StartDate,AdmitPatientBed.EndDate)*24 from AdmitPatientBed where  APBId = 4)

select @firstdate-@seconddate as hours
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like (can't be sure because you don't say what your database is:

```
select 
  DATEDIFF(Day, StartDate,AdmitPatientBed.EndDate) days,
  DATEDIFF(hh,AdmitPatientBed.StartDate , AdmitPatientBed.EndDate) -
  (DATEDIFF(Day, StartDate,AdmitPatientBed.EndDate)*24)  hours
from 
  AdmitPatientBed
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some inbuilt functions in the crystal Report like data diff, which helps in getting the desired result, you just have to write what sort of difference you want and start date and the end date.

```
DateDiff (intervaltype,startdate ,enddate )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulus operator (`%` in SQL Server) to calculate the remainder in hours:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR,@STARTDATE, @ENDDATE) % 24
```

Or in Crystal format:

```
DateDiff("h", {@StartDate}, {@EndDate}) % 24
```